# Iterating through parent classes within a page, and determining if a child-class exists with the parent class using selenium in python

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to iterate through a parent class, defined as:

```
cluster = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Rating__RatingBody-sc-1rhvpxz-0.dGrvXb")
```

within this parent class, there is an optional class, depending on if the reviewer chose to include this aspect with their review. Therefore, some parent classes have this child class, and some don't. I would like to iterate through through the parent classes, and if the child class does not exist, append an empty string to a list, and if the child class exists, I would like to append the child class value to the same list.
The child class is found as:

```
tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("RatingTags__StyledTags-sc-1boeqx2-0")
```

ideally, the list would look like:

```
results = [' ', ' ', ' ', 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', ' ', 'tag4', ' ']
```

etc.
I am a bit lost, and have not made solid progress on this aspect in quite some time. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through parent if it's there append class to array.

```
lst=[]
for x in cluster:
   try:
       child=x.find_element_by_class_name("RatingTags__StyledTags-sc-1boeqx2-0")
       lst.append(child.get_attribute("class"))
   except:
       lst.append(' ')
```

Comment: Hi Arundeep, thanks for the answer, it is very close to what I want. If I wanted to extract the text value from these classes, how should I got about it? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Arundeep, no worries i figured it out by using the child.text, instead of child.get_attribute! Thanks!

Comment: Np i wasnt sure if you wanted the class or text.